# C++ Beginner level - trouble with array replacement

Tags: c++

So I am making a program that ask the user to input sentences and 10 digit phone number, and encode them together. Example if user input for sentences: Hello My name is Jackson. For phone number: 425 440 2345, then the output would be: H4llo My name is J2ackson.

What I would like it to do:

- If word start with capital letter, replace 2nd char to the digit
- If word is 1/2 characters long, skip it.

I am new to programming and have tried several things. I know the logic but I do not know how to input it to the code. I have tried several stuff the most recent one is the commented one.
What I am having trouble the most is how to replace a certain character in the array to the digit number. If anyone can help me or give guidance, would be much appreciated.

This is my code so far:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //variables
    char sentence[300];
    char phoneNum[10];
    int capital = 0;

    cout << "This program will ask the user to input sentences up to 300 characters long and ask the user for a 10 digit phone number. \nThe objective is to hide user phone number within the sentences. Have fun with it!" << endl;

    //Ask user for story/sentences up to 300 char long
    cout << "\nPlease enter any sentences or any story you like (up to 300 characters long and no numeric)" << endl;
    cin.get(sentence, 300);
    cin.ignore(300,'\n');
    cout << "\nYou enter: " << sentence << endl << endl;

    //Ask user for 10 digit phone number
    cout << "Please enter 10 digit phone number: ";
    cin.get(phoneNum, 10);
    cin.ignore(100,'\n');
    cout << "\nYou enter: " << phoneNum << endl;

    //Encode
    /*for (int i = 0; i <sentence.length();++i)
    {
        char c = sentence[i];
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            capital++;
    }*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sentence.length()` won't work. `char sentence[300]` is a plain C array - no member functions like `length()` available. You could use `std::string` which is cleaner C++ and has a member function `size()` for your purpose. At least, if you insist to stick to `char[300]`, you could use `std::strlen(sentence)`. (You have to `#include <cstring>` in this case.)

Comment: Do you know what `std::string` is?

Comment: According to your "rules", the string `Hello My name is Jackson.` should produce `H4llo My name is J2ckson` (without the `a` in `Jackson`).

Comment: You should make a `mcve` **without any user input**, with a function like this: `std::string my_strange_operation(const std::string& sentence, const std::string& phone)`, and a `main` which tests it. Use a debugger and don't use any I/O.